# Page methods not calling web service methods sometimes

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.NET, Unable to invoke **delIt** web service method in Defaults.aspx.cs from **ActionComplete** method. But am able to invoke **AddIt** and **UpdateIt** web methods in Defaults.aspx.cs

My code:

In Default.aspx:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True" />


function ActionComplete(args) {

            var ganttRecord = args.data;

            if (args.requestType === 'save' && args._cAddedRecord) {
                PageMethods.AddIt(ganttRecord);
            }
            else if (args.requestType === 'save') {
                PageMethods.UpdateIt(ganttRecord);
            }
            else if (args.requestType === 'delete') {
                PageMethods.delIt(ganttRecord);
            }
        }
```

In Default.aspx.cs:

```
        [WebMethod]
        public static void AddIt(TaskData record)
        {
            Default sample = new Default();
            sample.Add(record);

        }
        [WebMethod]
        public static void UpdateIt(TaskData record)
        {
            Default sample1 = new Default();
            sample1.Update(record);

        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static void delIt(TaskData record)
        {
            Default sample2 = new Default();
            sample2.Delete(record);

        }
```

Comment: What do you mean, "unable to invoke"? What happens when you try?

Comment: @John....Using page method I am able to call AddIt method UpdateIt method which is present in the Defaults.aspx.cs. But unable to call delIt method alone...

Comment: While debugging, for both AddIt method UpdateIt method, it is entering in to "eval code"dynamic page which contains following line "Sys.Net.XMLHttpExecutor". But for delIt method it is not entering in to that page... I don't know about that clearly...

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint on the first line of the `delIt` method?

Comment: @John....Break point is not hitting for that delIt method alone....Debugging exists after this line "PageMethods.delIt(ganttRecord);". But for other two methods it is calling their methods which is present in the Defaults.aspx.cs

Comment: @JohnR use callbacks to track the result... `PageMethods.delIt(ganttRecord,OnSuccess,OnError);`

Comment: I found the solution...The "ganttRecord" Json object which i passed to delIt method has some extra undefined variables and boolean variables. So only I think so Pagemethods unable to call that delIt method in the Defaults.aspx.cs

Answer (score 0):

The "ganttRecord" Json object which i passed to delIt method has some extra undefined variables and boolean variables. So only I think so Pagemethods unable to call that delIt method in the Defaults.aspx.cs