# Unable to call web method using AJAX post Jquery method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Unable to call `UpdateIt` method that presents in the `Default.aspx.cs` by using jQuery Ajax post method.

**In Default.aspx:**

```
function ActionComplete(args) {

    var ganttRecord = args.data; if (args.requestType === 'save') {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/UpdateIt", 
            data: ganttRecord,
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function () {
                alert("Fail");
            }
        });
    }
} function OnSuccess() {
    alert("Pass");
}
```

**In Default.aspx.cs:**

```
[WebMethod]
public static void UpdateIt(TaskData record)
{
    Default sample1 = new Default();
    sample1.Update(record);

}
```

Kindly help me...

Comment: Do you have Friendly Urls turned on? I've never been able to get those working happily together, but I know there are some workarounds out there that are supposed to work.

Comment: why are you converting .aspx page into webservice. there is web api,web service (.asmx), wcf for this.

Comment: Hope you are not repeating this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26479506/page-methods-not-calling-web-service-methods-sometimes

Comment: @Matthew I do not have friendly Urls in WebConfig file...

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi I could not understand properly what you are saying. Please share some example...

Comment: @Dnyanesh No I am repeating that query...In that query I used pagemethods for calling web methods.. But here am trying to use Ajax post method for calling that web method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i get it working.

Following is the code behind or server side code.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string UpdateIt(TaskData record)
{
    Update(record);
    return "done";
}
public static void Update(TaskData r)
{
   // Write code to handle whatever you need.
}
```

**NOTE:** `Update` method has to be `static` as it needs to be called from `static` method. Also you don't need to create a instance of `page` class such as `Default` and then invoke `Update` method like this - `sample1.Update(record);`. Because you can definitely call `Update` directly, as it resides in `Default.aspx.cs`. That is why, i have used `Update(record)` inside `UpdateIt(TaskData record)`.

**Assumption** `TaskData` has following structure.

```
public class TaskData
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Next, look carefully at JS code.

```
var tskmgr = { 'record': {"id":"2" , "name": "ajax is happy"} };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/UpdateIt",
    data: JSON.stringify(tskmgr),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        // alert(data.d);// this will show alert as "done". Check serverside code for more detail
        console.log(data);
    },
    failure: function (a,b,c) {
        alert("Fail");
    }
});
```

Take a look at JS structure, `record` is parameter name, i have used that first, then parameter value is object so , i have used object with required properties, then i have used `JSON.stringify` to send them to server side.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: That works fine now after changing the data...Arindam

Answer (score 1):

What is this ??  data: ganttRecord

It should be like this,

```
      data: '{"param" ,"value"}',

    ADD THIS
      JSON.stringify({'ganttRecord'})


     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Change

```
      public static void
```

TO

```
      public static string
```

Comment: JSON.stringify({'ganttRecord'}) This will call function correctly I  had made changes in answer,try it